# Not getting the receive message from AWS SQS using Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sqs

I am a beginner trying to setup AWS SQS for the first time. I am referring the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html to send and receive messages. I am able to send message and it populates in AWS as well. But when I run the receive file, it doesn't give me anything. Neither success not error message.

Steps I followed -
I downloaded awscli, ran aws configure and entered all the details like access ID, secret key and session token.

When I run send-message, it gives me a success

```
sqs-message % node send-message.js   
(node:99440) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.

Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Success 9613ace8-c71f-4188-bb69-717f8c05439d
```

when I run receive message -

```
sqs-message % node receive-message.js
(node:99717) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.

Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Could anyone tell me why is it not working for receive message? I am following the instruction mentioned on the aws doc.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SQS queues internally store messages across multiple SQS servers, which introduces a delay in data replication, resulting in eventual consistency. As a result, when you tried to run the `sqs_receivemessage.js` script immediately after the `sqs_sendmessage.js` script, you received an empty response, and that's why you didn't encounter any errors.

The `sqs_receivemessage.js` script contains the `WaitTimeSeconds` parameter value set to 0, which enables short-polling. In short-polling, the SQS request queries only a subset of SQS servers, which increases the likelihood of receiving an empty response. However, if you execute the same script after a few seconds, it will fetch the published message from the queue.

If you prefer to receive messages even on the first attempt, you should use [long polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-enable-long-polling.html), which attempts to fetch messages from all SQS servers. To enable long polling, set the `WaitTimeSeconds` value to 1-20 seconds. With long polling, the request will wait until it receives the `MaxNumberOfMessages` count specified in the request parameter or until the maximum configured `WaitTimeSeconds` is reached, whichever comes first.